# Inserting this long SQL query into PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I have this SQL query running perfectly on my server, but I'm building a website that does something to me easier and I need help deploying it to PHP.

Check the PHP code and try to give me the working version as im not familiar into PHP and its not working.

```
<?php
// Set up variables for the query values
$login = "test.me";
$password = "P@ssw0rd";
$salt = "6B29FC40-CA47-1067-B31D-00DD010662DA";
$group = "Dispatcher";

// Create a new SQL Server connection
$serverName = "192.168.200.110";
$connectionInfo = array( 
    "Database"=>"test1",
    "UID"=>"test",
    "PWD"=>"ptest",
    "TrustServerCertificate"=>true
    );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

// Prepare the query statement
$query = "BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON
            DECLARE @NewValue INT;
            DECLARE @salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID()
            BEGIN TRY

                INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, Salt,Active, [group])
                VALUES(@pLogin, HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pPassword+CAST(@salt AS NVARCHAR(36))), @salt, 1, @group)
                SET @NewValue = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
                
                INSERT INTO Employees select @FirstName, ISNULL(@LastName, ''), '' , '', '', IIF(LOWER(@group) = 'dispatcher' or LOWER(@group) = 'teamleader', 1, null), @NewValue, 'dbo', GETDATE(),'', 0 ,null,null
            
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
            select 0
            END CATCH
            END";

$params = array($login, $password, $salt, $salt, $group);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

This is my code from SQL Server:

```
USE [me]
GO
/** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Sp_CreateEmployeeAndUser]**/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Sp_CreateEmployeeAndUser] (
    @pLogin NVARCHAR(50), 
    @pPassword NVARCHAR(50),
    @Group NVARCHAR(50),
    @FirstName nvarchar(50),
    @LastName nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @NewValue INT;
    DECLARE @salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID()
    BEGIN TRY

        INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, Salt,Active, [group])
        VALUES(@pLogin, HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pPassword+CAST(@salt AS NVARCHAR(36))), @salt, 1, @group)
        SET @NewValue = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        
    insert into Employees select @FirstName, ISNULL(@LastName, ''), '' , '', '', IIF(LOWER(@group) = 'dispatcher' or LOWER(@group) = 'teamleader', 1, null), @NewValue, 'dbo', GETDATE(), '', 0 ,null,null
     
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    select 0
    END CATCH
END
```

I tried to make a small query but for sure I'm missing a lot. I would like some help in this as its my first time doing that large query into PHP.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, Salt, Active, [group])
          VALUES (?, HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', ? + CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(36))), ?, 1, ?);
          SET @NewValue = SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
```

POSSIBLE SOLUTION:

```
<?php

$login = "test.test";
$password = "P@ssw0rd";
$salt = "example_salt";
$group = "Dispatcher";

// Connect to the SQL Server database
$serverName = "192.168.200.110";
$connectionInfo = array( 
    "Database"=>"test1",
    "UID"=>"test",
    "PWD"=>"test",
    "TrustServerCertificate"=>true
    );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

// Call the stored procedure
$procedureName = "{call [dbo].[Sp_CreateEmployeeAndUser] (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}"; // replace with the name of your stored procedure and the appropriate number of placeholders
$params = array($login, $password, $group, 'pj', 'pj'); // replace with the values for your parameters
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $procedureName, $params);
if (!$stmt) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Process the results
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['group'] . "\n"; // replace with the name of the column(s) you want to retrieve
}

// Close the connection
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

My latest code edit:

```
$procedureName = "{EXEC [dbo].[Sp_CreateEmployeeAndUser] (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}"; 
$procedure_params = array(
    array($login, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array($password, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array($group, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array('pj', SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array('pj', SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
    );
with the values for your parameters
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $procedureName, $procedure_params);
```

The error:

```
Warning: sqlsrv_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\proccall.php on line 28
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_prepare. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_prepare. ) )
```

Comment: Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Comment: What exactly is the question / problem? It's unclear what you want us to tell you.

Comment: @ADyson I help figuring out if this can be done ?  i never tried this long query and im wondering

Comment: By "small query" do you mean the result set or the select statement? Is it not working?  You say you're wondering, but have you actually tried it?

Comment: @mykaf small query like this one (I edited my post )
But I'm missing those lines :
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @ NewValue INT;
DECLARE @ salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID()

Comment: Try it first, and see what happens, that's better than wondering. But if it doesn't work (e.g. because sqlrv_query only lets you execute single statements, perhaps) then my advice would be to put this code into a stored procedure in the database, and let PHP call the stored procedure.

Comment: @ADyson can you show me how to call a stored procedure with PHP to SQL Server ?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php)?

Comment: with the EXEC command, same as you call it normally. But yeah, please [do some simple research](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+sqlsrv+stored+procedure) before asking for help, you can usually find what you need without it requiring other people's time.

Comment: What's preventing you from adding the lines you are missing? `SET NOCOUNT ON DECLARE @ NewValue INT; DECLARE @ salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID()`?

Comment: Please check my edited version, thanks a lot ! i did not know that we can call them like that! Thanks to @ADyson Can you check my last edit ?

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Well what happens when you test it? I'd expect it should be EXEC though rather than CALL, as per the links I provided.

Comment: I linked to php documentation. Of course MySQL will be different than SQL Server. You asked how to call stored procedure with PHP. This is how you call a stored procedure in PHP. Plug in the correct syntax for the database you are using.

Comment: @mykaf **I** didn't ask that, it was the OP. And yes, MySQL will be different than SQL Server. You linked to PHP documentation which **specifically** tells how to call _MySQL_ procedures using the `mysqli` library. It's _entirely useless_ for working with _SQL Server_ from PHP. That requires a completely different PHP code library (`sqlsrv`) with substantially different commands and syntax. And the mySQL stored procedure syntax is substantially different from SQL Server. There is no generic "php documentation" for this, it's very different in each case. Sorry but your comment is plain wrong.

Comment: @ADyson, I see what you're saying. My apologies.

Comment: @mykaf no problem, every day is a school day :-)

Comment: @ADyson kindly check my latest edit of the code while i changed the call to EXEC and i got an error maybe it will help you find me the solution

Comment: The message indicates that `$conn` is `false` instead of holding a connection object. This means your connection attempt failed. Add some error handling after the `sqlsrv_connect` command to find out why

Comment: @ADyson how to give you credit ?
My code works now!!!

Comment: What was wrong with the connection?

Comment: I accidently edit my code to copy it here, so when i tested your thing i did not work till I fixed the server connection credentials xD!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to put this code into a stored procedure in the database, and let PHP call the stored procedure. For example:

```
$procedureName = "{EXEC [dbo].[Sp_CreateEmployeeAndUser] (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}"; 
$procedure_params = array(
    array($login, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array($password, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array($group, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array('pj', SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array('pj', SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
    );
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $procedureName, $procedure_params);
sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
```